# Git-remote-https permission denied

Tags: android, git

I am using Android terminal IDE and I am trying to pull the master branch into my phone.  I have done the following:

```
git config --global user.name "name"
git config --global user.email email
git init
git remote add origin http://github.com/blahblahblah
git clone https://github.com/blahblahblah
```

Typing git status gives me nothing to commit (on branch master).  When I typed the last line above it gives me:

```
Cloning into 'blah'...
fatal: cannot exec 'git-remote-https': Permission denied
```

Thanks for helping!

Edit: This question is not identical to the other one because the other one has the wrong url.  I am sure that I have the correct url.

Comment: Have you tried cloning with SSH? Also if that doesn't work, I believe you haven't added your SSH keys to your Github account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resolve a permission denied error with git-remote-https?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161227/how-can-i-resolve-a-permission-denied-error-with-git-remote-https)

Comment: @JaredBurrows not the same problem, my link is correct.  I will look into SSH.  Thanks.

Comment: @TheNomad I tried to get SSH and prompts another [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979701/is-the-terminal-ide-app-for-android-compatible-with-lollipop), thanks for helping.

Comment: @JasonTang Not too sure about using the `Android Terminal IDE`. But when in doubt, just use the Git Shell if you are using Windows. Or just use `Terminal` if on Mac.

Comment: @TheNomad I have this same problem. I tried SSH. I get this error: `ssh: connection to git@github.com:22 exited: Didn't validate host key`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`